# Phase Portraits of Linear System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have following linear system:
$\left\{\begin{matrix}
{x_1}'=x_2\\ 
{x_2}'=1
\end{matrix}\right.$

solution to this system is: $x_{1}^{2}=\frac{1}{2}x_2^{2}+c$, where $c$ is constant. So I know that the phase portrait would be consists of parabolas, but I do not understand how to determine direction.

In general I know that direction is determined according eigenvalues, but here are both zeros.

Any help?

Comment: If your calculation was $\frac{dx_1}{dx_2}=\frac{x_2}{1}$, then this implies $x_1=\frac12x_2^2+c$, which indeed has parabola as curves. In the text above there is a square too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already $x_2'>0$ tells you the direction: you should be going upwards in the $x_1x_2$-plane.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Solutions are of the form
$$
x_1(t) = t + c_1, \quad x_2(t) = \frac 12 t^2 + c_1 t + c_2
$$

This parametric form lets you know is which sense are you moving on integral curves.

Comment: Can you please elaborate solution?

Comment: you can clearly solve $x_2'=1$ for $x_2(t) = t+c$. Then plug this solution into the other DE and integrate.

Comment: @Meowdog I can but I still do not understand direction

Comment: @MartinN. Choose a point $(x_1(t), x_2(t))$ and watch what happens when $t$ increases...